# Understanding Houghlines command in Matlab

Tags: hough-transform

[image: ...]

I created this picture with paint to understand the hough transform but i realized something funny by using `houghlines(bw,theta,rho,peaks)` in matlab.

```
I=imread('deneme.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);
bw = edge(I,'sobel');
[H,theta,rho] = hough(bw);
peaks  = houghpeaks(H,1); % I select a peak which is maximum
lines = houghlines(bw,theta,rho,peaks);
```

Matlab found [image: workspace]

peaks=[1097 55]

[image: H matrix[2]]

If we look at the lines variable [image: Lines Variable]

And using plot command , i showed where these points provided by lines.

```
imshow(bw)
hold on
plot(lines.point1(1),lines.point1(2),'r*')
plot(lines.point2(1),lines.point2(2),'r*')
```

[image: points]

My question is why these red points here.

Instead of being here , should they be at the start of the line and end of the line ?

And where those points come from.

r=x cos(theta) + y sin(theta)

from rho and theta , we can obtain this equation. But not the points

Thank you